# Move Kivy window by label drag - Kivy, Python

Tags: python, click, kivy, drag, motionevent

I want to create custom window header of a Kivy window. I am very new to kivy so please provide some explanation how the events work. I need to simply move the window by "moving" the label.

First of all I want to know, why this does call any function when I click or drag the label. It is in KvLang:

```
#:import main main.window

CustBoxLayout:
<CustBoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Label:
        id: header
        text: 'MyApp'
        font_size: 24
        padding_x: 16
        color: self.theme_cls.primary_color

        on_touch_down: main.click
        on_touch_move: main.move

...
```

Any function is not called when I click or drag the label. However if I change `main.click` to for example `print('touched!')` it works.

So I created my own class:

```
class HeadLabel(MaterialLabel):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        window.click(touch)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        window.drag(touch)
```

This works. But now I don't know how to get the screen position out of the `MotionEvent` event. This is my actual code of window:

```
class WindowApp(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Light'
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Purple'

        return CustBoxLayout()

    def click(self, touch):
        self.touch_x, self.touch_y = touch.spos[0], touch.spos[1]

    def drag(self, touch):
        Window.top = self.touch_y + touch.spos[0]
        Window.left = self.touch_x + touch.spos[1])
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a class for the custom *Label* and implement *on_touch_down* and *on_touch_move* methods. Please refer to the example below for details.

[Programming Guide » Input management » Touch event basics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4538J.png)

> By default, touch events are dispatched to all currently displayed
>   widgets. This means widgets receive the touch event whether it occurs
>   within their physical area or not.
>
> In order to provide the maximum flexibility, Kivy dispatches the
>   events to all the widgets and lets them decide how to react to them.
>   If you only want to respond to touch events inside the widget, you
>   simply check for collision.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager


class CustomLabel(Label):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print("\nCustomLabel.on_touch_down:")

        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print("\ttouch.pos =", touch.pos)
            self.touch_x, self.touch_y = touch.spos[0], touch.spos[1]
            return True
        return super(CustomLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        print("\nCustomLabel.on_touch_move:")

        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print("\ttouch.pos =", touch.pos)
            Window.top = self.touch_y + touch.spos[0]
            Window.left = self.touch_x + touch.spos[1]
            return True
        return super(CustomLabel, self).on_touch_move(touch)


class CustBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Light'
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Purple'

        return CustBoxLayout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<CustomLabel>:


<CustBoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    CustomLabel:
        id: header
        text: 'MyApp'
        font_size: 24
        padding_x: 16
        color: app.theme_cls.primary_color

    Button:
        text: 'Button Widget'
        font_size: 24
        padding_x: 16
        color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - on touch down]
[image: Img02 - on touch move]